# Tables/database/literature of specific or optical rotation

Tags: experimental-chemistry, spectroscopy, stereochemistry, reference-request

I'm looking for a comprehensive reference of experimental [specific rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_rotation) or [optical rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_rotation) data. It can be a published literature review, a free web database with API access or one that permits scraping, or even a table on a web page with references.

ChemSpider pages link to outside sources (I think only chemical suppliers) for optical rotation, but this is problematic:

- it's unclear what molecules contain this information (not all stereoisomers do),
- not all the product specification pages on the suppliers' websites actually contain the data,
- the values aren't available through the ChemSpider API, and
- it's forbidden to screen scrape ChemSpider pages.

The story seems to be similar for PubChem, though they allow scraping within reason.

For example, [here](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/cr990044u) is a review collecting experimental electron affinities for a large number of small molecules and elemental clusters. It's fine that this isn't web-based, because all the values are together and in bulk; writing a PDF scraper is worthwhile because there are so many entries.

Also acceptable would be a book, such as the comprehensive reference from [Huber and Herzberg](https://archive.org/details/MolecularSpectraAndMolecularStructureIV.ConstantsOfDiatomicMoleculesK.P.HuberG.Herzberg) that contains rotational constants, bond lengths, and other constants for diatomic molecules.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that reference on electron affinities, it looks quite interesting

Comment: Have you already had a look at [the Handbook of Chemistry and Physics](http://www.hbcpnetbase.com/)? I am not too familiar with the work, so this is just a suggestion. They have many different values, if the ones you are looking for are among them, I don't know.

Comment: The sigma-aldrich website? They provide optical rotation for most of their chiral compounds

Comment: @pentavalentcarbon did you find an answer?

Comment: @Polydynamical at some point I discovered my dead tree copy of the Merck Index has many, but they are associated with each entry and are not in a separate table. I never did look at the HBCP or S-A website, nor did I find a "holy grail" type resource :(

Comment: @pentavalentcarbon Wow I didn't even think you would respond. I guess I'll just compile my own dataset. If I ever do compile it, I'll drop you a link :)

Comment: @Polydynamical It is not so easy to get rid of me. I had also found ~soon after asking this question https://brunl01.users.greyc.fr/CHEMISTRY/. Converting this into a pile of JSON would be a great starting point.

Comment: @pentavalentcarbon YOO this is exactly what I was looking for. The format, the data... perfect. The only thing is, that I need about 1000x the data . . . :)

Comment: @pentavalentcarbon UPDATE: I was just reading a paper and they extracted the optical activity data from the Reaxys database: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2110.04383.pdf (middle of page 8 & page 30)

Comment: There seems to be a way of searching for the compounds with optical rotation with Pubchem at this [link](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/#input_type=list&query=0pV0AmBmBdoy9I3tD5XEwWRH2Scdge8GlSP0So4y5kuOK9o&collection=compound&alias=PubChem%3A%20PubChem%20Compound%20TOC%3A%20Optical%20Rotation)

Comment: I've made some progress! [Here's](https://www.govinfo.gov/content/pkg/GOVPUB-C13-b9c7e853f193dd4e6daf23352adaa5a3/pdf/GOVPUB-C13-b9c7e853f193dd4e6daf23352adaa5a3.pdf) a book from 1932 that contains a whole bunch of optical rotation tables.